# My financial conditions?

Tags: sentence-construction

Does the following sentence sound fine?

> Now, I'm looking for any opportunity that will be able to improve my
>   financial shape/condition

I tried to say that I want to have more money than I do now.

Comment: Personally, I'd go without the "be able to". It makes it feel really wordy and sounds a bit wishy-washy. You want an opportunity that **will** improve your financial position, not one that might.

Comment: As an expansion of why I support D.B.'s comment, consider the difference between "I am able to cure your mother's cancer" and "I will cure your mother's cancer". To be able to do something is not necessarily a promise that you actually will do it. In some contexts it has that meaning, but not always.

Answer (score 2):

"Improving you financial shape or condition" suggests changing the way you have arranged your affairs, not that you want more money. The phrase suggests analyzing the places you have your money and moving it around to better look after the future of you and your family.

Variations on your sentence that convey wanting more money include:

> Now, I'm looking for any opportunity that will increase my finances.
>
> Now, I'm looking for an opportunity to earn more money
>
> I am looking for a bank to rob

I do not recommend the last method.

Comment: I'd rather say "I'm looking for **an** opportunity to earn more money", or "I'm looking for **a** bank to rob". As written your examples aren't teaching fluent English.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thank you for pointing out out those improvements.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I am looking for an opportunity to improve my financial situation.

Is how I would say it.  Or

> Now, I am looking for opportunities to improve my financial situation.

Saying that you are looking for **any** opportunity sounds desperate and for me includes things like illegal activities.

Or if you are desperate

> Now, I am willing to consider any opportunity that would improve my financial situation.

The word *shape* sounds more like a physical attribute (such as your body shape) and the word *condition* also sounds more physical (such as a medical condition)

On a minimum I would remove some extra words as Catija suggested in the comments and go with

> Now, I'm looking for any opportunity to improve my financial shape/condition